# Benefits of mentioning `index-state` in `cabal.project` file

Tags: haskell, cabal

I keep on seeing the mention of `index-state` in `cabal.project` file. I can see one use case mentioned in cabal [docs](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-project.html#cfg-field-index-state):

> This is particularly useful in combination with freeze-files in order to also freeze the state the package index was in at the time the install-plan was frozen.

But I think there is more to it.

Comment: I think it's mostly just a way of protecting oneself from the annoying surprises that tend to happen when a `cabal update` executed elsewhere causes it to also decide to build this project with a different set of dependencies – i.e., long lags for re-building dependencies at least, failures at worst. But not sure. I personally am not a fan of this – IMO Cabal should just more aggressively try to use already installed packages. This wouldn't completely prevent occasional surprises – but for the case where it's _necessary_ that a build goes through as it did previously, we have Stack after all.

Comment: What makes you think there is more to it?

Comment: @Noughtmare Yes, I see it being used in IOG's Cardano libraries such as [cardano-node](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/cabal.project), all of which use [Cardano haskell package repository](https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-haskell-packages/) which specifically mentions about `index-state`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I personally would rather Cabal's behaviour is a function of Hackage and of my package files, and is independent of any past builds of this or any other project I may have run previously, so that I can see more similar behaviour when different machines build the same project. Being affected by previous builds was a major component of cabal hell (which leads to sandboxing to avoid it, which leads to even *less* reuse of existing packages). And if it's a function of those two things, it's very nice to be able to easily control when the Hackage input changes.

Comment: Is it that mentioning `index-state` helps in reproducible builds in relation with `nix`?

Answer (score 3):

The index state just locks in a particular hackage index (identified by date). This prevents your build from breaking due to changes to the package index.

My previous company had a build break because package X depended on Y. We had a freeze file which specified the versions for both packages. This isn't sufficient because Hackage has 'revisions' which are changes to the .cabal file (usually dependency version bounds). A new revision was set to exclude the version of Y we used from building with package X, so our build broke. If the build used `index-state` then the build system would not have seen this new revision and things would have continued to function. As it stood the whole team had to pause work (or at least pause testing with the normal process) to get this ironed out.

Comment: Is it a convention to pin `index-state` when working with reproducible build systems such as `nix`?

Comment: @Sourabh for my nixified Haskell work I don't even have a freeze file. I can't say if that is convention or not.